# NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. (Spring Boot / Security / React / Redux)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, post, fetch, response

When sending a post request for sign-up with POSTMAN it works as usual and here's the output :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEzqe.png)

But when i try to send a post request from my react app running on port 3000, IT ADDs THE USER to my database BUT does not respond back and i get a "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

Here is my api call:

```
//sign up req
export const signupApi = async (payload) => {
    try{
        const resp =  await fetch("/api/auth/signup",{
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                 Accept: 'application/json',
                                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                            },
                            body : JSON.stringify(payload)
                        });
        console.log("SIGNUP RESP : "+ JSON.parse(resp))
    }catch(e){
        console.log("SIGN UP ERROR" + e)
    }
}
```

my saga:

```
function* signupAsync(action){
    try {
        console.log("i made it before calling be")
        const resp = yield call(signupApi,action.data);
        console.log("i made it after calling be")
        yield put(signupRequestSuccessAction(resp));
    }
    catch (e){
        console.log("Caught the error :"+e)
    }
}

export function* watchSignup(){
    yield takeLatest(SIGN_UP_REQUEST, signupAsync);
}
```

my action:

```
export const signupRequestAction = (data) => {
    return({
        type: SIGN_UP_REQUEST,
        data: data
    })
}

export const signupRequestSuccessAction = (data) => {
    return({
        type: SIGN_UP_REQUEST_SUCCESS,
        data: data
    })
}
```

and my reducer :

```
const signupReducer = (state = "", action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SIGN_UP_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
            return action.data;
        case SIGN_UP_REQUEST_FAILURE:
                return action.data;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default signupReducer;
```

NOTE: spring server runnning on port 8080

any help would be amazing! thank you